# Error 1054 When query multiple phone numbers

Tags: mysql

I got an error code 1054, when I try to query multiple phone numbers in my statement. I am VERY new to MYSQL and can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

I can query one phone number with no problem, but if I add more than one I get the 1054 error. Can anyone give me some insight on what I am doing wrong? The code I am using is below:

```
SELECT
    member_id, first_name, last_name
FROM
    database_name.billing
WHERE
    phone in (‘310-123-6528’,'213-123-4564',.......);
```

I tried to research it and couldn't find anything, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I copied your code, I noticed that inside the "IN" you are using different limiters, ' and '. Try to check if this is it, if it is not post your SQL tidy, please.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-back-ticks-in-mysql

Comment: This question serves as an example of why we should advise *against* using Microsoft Word or Outlook (with the "smart-quotes"quote character replacement feature enabled) as an editor for SQL text. And beyond just the 1054 error code, the MySQL error also includes a message that indicates what it thinks is an invalid identifier, and which part of the statement the identifier is found in.

Answer (score 1):

you are using `´` in the first case, try use `'`

Answer (score 0):

The error message from MySQL includes the identifier (what MySQL is seeing as the column name) and which part of the statement it's finding it.

For example,

```
 Unknown column 'foo' in 'field list'
```

... tells us that MySQL is seeing a reference to a column named `foo` in an expression in the SELECT list. And this

```
 Unknown column 'foo' in 'where clause'
```

tells us the problem is in the `WHERE` clause, MySQL is "seeing" a reference ot a column named "foo".

This information helps us figure out where the the problem is.

Comment: It does look like it was the word editor.  Thanks!!!